# Sending sms message from a C# Application problem. @ becomes an inverted exclamation point

Tags: c#, sms, gsm

I made a short code that will be used in sending employees with a copy of their email address. I use LTE modem. My problem is that the email format received by the employee is incorrect, @ is converted into  an inverted exclamatory point and I don't know the cause of this problem. I tried some keys and it works fine.

```
 try
            {

                string Message = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("EMP_EMAILADD")) + Environment.NewLine + "( THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MESSAGE - PLEASE DO NOT REPLY)";


                SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
                sp.PortName = Properties.Settings.Default.ModemPort;//modem portname
                sp.Open();
                sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.WriteLine("AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("EMP_CELLPHONE")).Trim() + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.WriteLine(Message);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.Write(new byte[] { 26 }, 0, 1);
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                var response = sp.ReadExisting();
                if (response.Contains("ERROR"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed!", "FAILED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sent!", "SUCCESS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                sp.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Modem is not available");
            }
```

Comment: It sounds like an encoding problem most likely. The GSM character set differs from what’s used on the computer. This may be a good reference: https://www.clockworksms.com/blog/the-gsm-character-set-in-net/

Comment: Also https://www.clockworksms.com/blog/the-gsm-character-set/